Omission of prepositions and conjunctions in present participial phrases
I found three sentences where a present participle are used as an adverbial phrase. I've actually asked about something related to this but I confused respondents because of the term (quasi-complement) I used in that post, so I would like to hear your opinion again. What do these examples mean?

I got emotional listening to this song.

Coworker cut his hair using mirrors.

Do you think you'll be okay waiting here by yourself?


Why do people often omite prepositions, conjunctions or a comma in these kinds of sentences? Is there any certain rule?

I got emotional [by / in / while] listening to this song.

Coworker cut his hair [by] using mirrors.

Do you think you'll be okay [in / while] waiting here by yourself?



I suppose, because the sentences are perfectly understandable without any preposition or conjunction!

Regarding 1, I think it would be better not to omit it since it can be interpreted in two ways: "while listening" and as the means by which the main action occurs. Or is it a casual expression often used in spoken language?

Yes, the participial clause can have both a temporal and a causal meaning and the word while somewhat weakens the causal sense and strengthens the temporal sense. If I say "I got emotional listening to that song" there is the very strong likelihood that the song brought on the feelings in me; that meaning is almost guaranteed; but if I say "I got emotional while listening to that song", I am opening the door to something else having caused my emotion, perhaps a memory I had during the song.

Thank you for the explanation. To be honest, my English skills were not good enough to understand the difference between the plural meanings of the present participle, especially in this case where an omission occurs, because I've only seen the ones with commas, conjunctions and prepositions. However, it was good to know that when a native speaker sees a sentence like 1, they definitely see it as a causal meaning. Lastly, are the implied parts in 2 and 3 correct? I added them, but I'm not sure about the answer and I'm worried.

Didn't coworker cut his hair [by] using scissors?

People aren't omitting prepositions or conjunctions here, they're using a well-known grammatical structure. It's like you can say "I saw a black dog" or "I saw a dog which was black": two ways to express the same thing.

"Coworker cut his hair using mirrors." isn't grammatical, by the way. It needs a determiner before "coworker" (depending on if the coworker was cutting their own hair or not, maybe "his", "the", or "a").
